# pass ndb.Model object in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

using the python appengine:
what is the recommended economical way to pass an ndb entity to another handler. let's say on the login handler I verify the user by fetching the ndb entity for the user. then in another handler I need some of the properies, incl the key.

Should I pass all properties and the key in the session dictionary? Or load the entity in memcache or use a global variable ?

Is using a global var considered acceptable from a thread point of view? If another user logs in and it is handled by the same app instance then is there a problem?

I have read Programming GAE and there is no explicit advice on best practice in such a common situation such as passing an object. Sanderson has an example on p39 which shows he is calling the datastore twice in order to use the object (see the PrefsPage method on p41.) Then he shows how to use Memcache in order to avoid calling the db. In the Memcache chapter he also advises to use the memcache for such requests.

It looks like using a global var is not a good idea. I am currently using the session dict to pass the info.
Thanks everybody.

Comment: Don't go with memcache due to being volatile.

Comment: In the example above, you want to pass the User model to a different handler or just have it persist requests?

Comment: pass it to another handler.  I am not concerned about volatility, the entity will be used within 10min. Setting it as a global was not working, but after moving the class def into my main file it works. sth must be wrong with my import of the models which were in a separate file.

Comment: re-think what you are doing.  webapp2 is a wsgi app.  Think about using middleware to perform authentication.  Store state/session in a session object, (which may use memcahce) or thread local storage.